# Socket TCP in linux - Client cannot insert username

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpclient, serversocket

I'm having troubles with implementing a signin/signup system with TCP/IP sockets.

So, whenever I want the user to signup, the client cannot insert the username, but he can insert the password. It looks like it is skipping one step.

Here is the code.

**Client**

```c
void func(int sockfd)
{
    char username[MAX], password[MAX];
    int n, c;

    bzero(username, sizeof(username));
    printf("Enter the username : ");
    n = 0;
    while ((username[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
        ;
    write(sockfd, username, sizeof(username));
    bzero(username, sizeof(username));

    bzero(password, sizeof(password));
    printf("Enter the password : ");
    c = 0;
    while ((password[c++] = getchar()) != '\n')
        ;
    write(sockfd, password, sizeof(password));
    bzero(username, sizeof(password));
}

...

int choice, ans;
    
func(sockfd);

bzero(buffer, 255);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
if(n < 0)
    error("Error reading from socket");
printf("Server - %s", buffer);
scanf("%d", &choice);
write(sockfd, &choice, sizeof(int));
    
if(choice == 1) {
    func(sockfd);
}


if(choice == 3) {
    printf("Session terminated\n");
    close(sockfd);
}

close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

**Server**

```c
void func(int newsockfd)
{
    char username[MAX], password[MAX];
    int n;

    bzero(username, MAX);
    read(newsockfd, username, sizeof(username));
    printf("From client: %s\n", username);

    bzero(password, MAX);
    read(newsockfd, password, sizeof(password));
    printf("From client pass: %s\n", password);

    while ((username[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
        ;

    write(newsockfd, username, sizeof(username));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    func(newsockfd);

    int num1, num2, ans, choice;

    n = write(newsockfd, "Benvenuto, inserisci una scelta: \n1. Registrazione\n2. Login\n3. Esci\n", strlen("Benvenuto, inserisci una scelta: \n1. Registrazione\n2. Login\n3. Esci\n"));
    if(n < 0) error("Error writing to socket");
    read(newsockfd, &choice, sizeof(int));

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            func(newsockfd);
            break;
        
        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:
            close(newsockfd);
            close(sockfd);
    }
    
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example:

[image]

Comment: You are ignoring the value returned by `read()`. You can't write correct netwrok programs that way. It could be -1, it could be zero, or it could be anything between 1 and the length you supplied, both inclusive. Correct your code and re-test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I fixed the code as you suggested but the program is still broken.

The function func(....) works fine before the switch.. but whenever i insert func(.....) in the case 1, then the client can't insert the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that the code provided is not complete code, the client and server are not even speaking the same protocol, so of course you are running into problems.

The client is sending the username and password to the server before it has even received the server's initial prompt.

The server is expecting the first input from the client to be the user's choice to the prompt, but the client is sending the username first, so the first few characters the server receives will be misinterpreted as an integer.

When the server does expect to receive a username and password, it sends back the username, which the client does not read.

You are also completely ignoring the return values of `read()` and `write()`.  And you are not handling received strings properly, either.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

**Shared**

```c
int sendAll(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    int n;

    while (len > 0) {
        n = send(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (n < 0) return n;
        pbuf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 0;
}

int recvAll(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    int n;

    while (len > 0) {
        n = recv(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (n <= 0) return n;
        pbuf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 1;
}

int sendInt32(int sockfd, int32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    return sendAll(sockfd, &value, sizeof(value));
}

int recvInt32(int sockfd, int32_t *value)
{
    int n = recvAll(sockfd, value, sizeof(*value));
    if (n == 1) *value = ntohl(*value);
    return n;
}

int sendStr(int sockfd, const char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    int n = sendInt32(sockfd, len);
    if (n == 0) n = sendAll(sockfd, str, len);
    return n;
}

int recvStr(int sockfd, char **str)
{
    *str = NULL;

    int32_t len;
    int n = recvInt32(sockfd, &len);
    if (n <= 0) return n;

    *str = malloc(len + 1);
    if (*str == NULL) return -1;

    n = recvAll(sockfd, *str, len);
    if (n <= 0) {
        free(*str);
        *str = NULL;
        return n;
    }

    (*str)[len] = '\0';
    return 1;
}
```

**Client**

```c
void func(int sockfd)
{
    char input[MAX+1];
    int n, c;

    printf("Enter the username : ");
    n = 0;
    while ((n < MAX) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
        input[n++] = (char) c;
    }
    input[n] = '\0';

    if (sendStr(sockfd, input) < 0)
        error("Error writing to socket");

    printf("Enter the password : ");
    n = 0;
    while ((n < MAX) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
        input[n++] = (char) c;
    }
    input[n] = '\0';

    if (sendStr(sockfd, input) < 0)
        error("Error writing to socket");

    char *ans;
    if (recvStr(sockfd, &ans) <= 0)
        error("Error reading from socket");

    printf("Server - %s: ", ans);
    free(ans);
}

int main() {
    int sockfd, choice;
    char *str;
    
    // connect to server...
    sockfd = ...;

    if (recvStr(sockfd, &str) <= 0)
        error("Error reading from socket");

    printf("Server - %s", str);
    free(str);

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (sendInt32(sockfd, choice) < 0)
        error("Error writing to socket");
    
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            func(sockfd);
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Session terminated\n");
            break;
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

**Server**

```c
void func(int sockfd, int choice)
{
    char *input;

    if (recvStr(sockfd, &input) <= 0)
        error("Error reading from socket");

    printf("From client user: %s\n", input);
    free(input);

    if (recvStr(sockfd, &input) <= 0)
        error("Error reading from socket");

    printf("From client pass: %s\n", input);
    free(input);

    char *ans = (choice == 1) ? "Registered" : "Logged in";
    if (sendStr(sockfd, ans) < 0)
        error("Error writing to socket");
}

int main() {

    int sockfd, clientsockfd, n;
    int32_t choice;

    // setup listening socket ...
    sockfd = ...;

    // accept client ...
    clientsockfd = ...;

    if (SendStr(clientsockfd, "Benvenuto, inserisci una scelta: \n1. Registrazione\n2. Login\n3. Esci\n") < 0)
        error("Error writing to socket");

    if (recvInt32(clientsockfd, &choice) < 0)
        error("Error reading from socket");

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            func(clientsockfd, choice);
            break;

        case 3:
            close(clientsockfd);
            break;
    }
    
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I used your code, but the issue is still present

Comment: @JonathanQuaranta then you are either not applying the lessons of my example to your code properly, or you are doing something else wrong that we can't see. The code I have given you should work when the client and socket are speaking the same protocol and are in sync with each other.

Answer (score 0):

a) can you printf("choice: %d\n", choice);
b) I have problems to see if the socket is blocked by your first function call
c) most important  - we have to focus on the fact, that you try to send serialized data (`int`) - that is totally other than sending plain text. Search google: "Network Byte Order":

```
 //client 
 uint32_t choice;
 choice = htons(choice);
 write(sockfd, &choice, sizeof(choice));

//server
uint32_t choice;
read(newsockfd, &choice, sizeof(uint32_t));
choice = ntohs(choice);

switch(choice);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer to me.

I printed the variable choice and the result was this:
If i press 1, it prints 1.
Same with 2, etc..

I tried your option (c) as suggested and this time choice became 156.

I think the problem should be (b), but how the socket could be blocked?

Comment: I assume - from what I can see - that when you call your `func()` (from the first call in main), the socket gets blocked. Can you try to close the socket in the func() function? Also can you update the code to your current working version?